# By what library and how can I scrape texts on an HTML by its heading and paragraph tags?

Tags: python, html, xpath, beautifulsoup, scrapy

My input will be any web documents that has no fixed HTML structure.
What I want to do is to extract the texts in the heading (might be nested) and its following paragraph tags (might be multiple), and output them as pairs.

A simple HTML example can be:

```
<h1>House rule</h1>
<h2>Rule 1</h2>
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<h2>Rule 2</h2>
<h3>Rule 2.1</h3>
<p>C</p>
<h3>Rule 2.2</h3>
<p>D</p>
```

For this example, I would like to have a output of pairs:

```
Rule 2.2, D

Rule 2.1, C

Rule 2, D

Rule 2, C

House rule, D

House rule, C

Rule 1, A B
```

.....and so on.

I am a beginner of Python, and I know the web scraping is widely done by Scrapy and BeautifulSoup, and it might require something to do with the XPath or code to identify sibling tags in this case. As how to extract the output pairs of the heading and its below paragraphs are obviously based on relative sequence of the tags. 
I am not sure which library will be better to use in this case, and it will be really helpful if you can show me how to achieve it. Thanks!

Comment: Why in your output is `Rule 2.2, E`? From where the letter `E` comes from?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it should be D instead of E for this example.

Comment: I see, but why there are `Rule 2, D` and `Rule 2, C`. What is the rule to assign to `Rule 2` D and C?

Comment: Hi Andrej, it is because the paragraph C and D are under <h3>, which are also contained in Rule 2 <h2>. The reason why I want to extract these pairs is because contents C and D should also be related to the topic of their <h2>, and even <h1> heading texts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traversing the tree and collecting all the `<p>` tags that are under increasing levels of `<h>` tags can be done with BeautifulSoup:

```
html = '''
<h1>House rule</h1>
    <h2>Rule 1</h2>
        <p>A</p>
        <p>B</p>
    <h2>Rule 2</h2>
        <h3>Rule 2.1</h3>
            <p>C</p>
        <h3>Rule 2.2</h3>
            <p>D</p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

counter = 1
all_leafs = []
while True:
    htag = 'h%d'%counter
    hgroups =  soup.findAll(htag)
    print(htag,len(hgroups))
    counter += 1
    if len(hgroups) == 0: 
        break
    for hgroup in hgroups:
        for c,descendant in enumerate(hgroup.find_all_next()):
            name = getattr(descendant, "name", None)
            if name == 'p':
                all_leafs.append((hgroup.getText(),descendant.getText()))
print(all_leafs)
```

...

```
h1 1
h2 2
h3 2
h4 0
[('House rule', 'A'), ('House rule', 'B'), ('House rule', 'C'), ('House rule', 'D'), ('Rule 1', 'A'), ('Rule 1', 'B'), ('Rule 1', 'C'), ('Rule 1', 'D'), ('Rule 2', 'C'), ('Rule 2', 'D'), ('Rule 2.1', 'C'), ('Rule 2.1', 'D'), ('Rule 2.2', 'D')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I wasn't aware that we can use a tree to do that. However, the paragraphs I want to pair with the heading tags should only be within the nested tag structure. For example, Rule 1 (h2) should only be paired with A and B (displayed together as best, like ('Rule 1', 'A B')) and shouldn't be paired with C and D, as C and D are within the Rule 2 (h2) nested structure. Likewise, Rule 2.1 (h3) should only be paired with C and Rule 2.2 (h3) should only be paired with D. Will that be achievable by using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Why is then "House Rule" paired with D and C in your example? I'm pretty sure that what  you're aiming for is doable with BeautifulSoup, which will allow you to traverse the structure of your markup, you need to figure out how this is done, and then collect the pairs according to the rules you set.

Comment: House Rule is in tag h1, which also contains Rule 2.1 and Rule 2.2 (h3) which has the text of C and D, so that is why I want to include them as pairs. But Rule 1 normally (other than this example having same heading structure) has nothing to do with C and D, because C and D are under Rule 2. And that is why I would exclude the pair of ('Rule 1', 'C') and ('Rule 1', 'D').