# BeautifulSoup4 findChildren() is empty

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use the `findChildren()` function. I basically want all the `<p>` under a particular `<h3>` tag. I'm trying a simple amount of code but the set `children`. I'm getting back is empty. `h3` returns the correct line (see `print(h3)` comment) and the `print(type(children))` prints type: `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
h3 = soup.find('h3', text=re.compile('chapter', re.IGNORECASE))
print(h3) #result prints <h3 style="text-align: center;">CHAPTER ONE - STEPHANUS GRAYLAND</h3>    
children = h3.findChildren('p')
print(type(children)) #returns type: <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
```

I also tried `h3.findChildren('p', Recursive=True)` and `children = h3.findChildren(Recursive=True)`. Which also come back empty.

Here's the section of HTML I'm trying to grab:

```
<h3 style="text-align: center;">CHAPTER ONE - STEPHANUS GRAYLAND</h3>
<p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;">
    <span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Stephanus Grayland did not try to hide his smile of satisfaction . He had “eaten” lunch, but now, he sensed, he would truly </span>
    <span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">feast</span>
    <span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">.</span>
</p>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Your `<p>` tags placed not in `h3` tag.

Comment: The relationship the `<p>` has to the `<h3>` is not "child", it's "following sibling".

Answer (score 0):

In the sample you provided, the `h3` node has no children. All of the `p` nodes are outside of that scope.

If you wrap your contents in a `div` (say) then you can see you're using the right technique

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div>' + contents + '</div>', 'html.parser')
>>> div = soup.find('div')
>>> div.findChildren('p')
[<p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Stephanus Grayland did not try to hide his smile of satisfaction . He had “eaten” lunch, but now, he sensed, he would truly </span><span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">feast</span><span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">.</span></p>, <p> </p>]
>>>
```

*Edit*

As you mention in your comments above, the `h3` and `p` nodes are siblings in the content you've supplied. I'm not sure it makes sense to have `p` elements that are children of `h3`, but if you did it would look like

```
<h3>
This content is within the h3 tag
<p>this is a child of h3</p>
<p>another child</p>
</h3>
<p>this is not a child of h3 as it is after the h3 close tag</p>
```

It's not really clear what the conditions for selecting `p` nodes in your example content should be - a simple `soup.find('p')` would return all of those tags, but I suspect you need to limit it in some way to prevent other content from being included. Can you elaborate? You possibly just want something like:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
>>> h3 = soup.find('h3')
>>> h3.find_next_sibling('p')
<p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;">
<span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Stephanus Grayland did not try to hide his smile of satisfaction . He had “eaten” lunch, but now, he sensed, he would truly </span>
<span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">feast</span>
<span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Is it because the children of a node have to be from a node with a parent?

Comment: @MeghanM. I've edited by answer to illustrate what it would look like with the `p` tags as children of the `h3` tag. Can you expand your example content with samples of what should be included vs excluded?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who responded. My problem is that `<h3>` and the sub `<p>`s are siblings not parent/child. I think these posts are what I'm after code-wise but my comment above remains. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571609/… and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852588/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your patience. I had to figure out how to get the html structure, prettify the html and write to a file to see the relationships better, etc. The pages I need to process (I didn't write them) have a structure as below. After building the bs4 structure, I figured out my desired content starts at the `<article..>` tag and ends at the beginning of the next `<script...> code here</<script> <h3>Comments</h3>`. I'm not sure how to terminate a search between two different tags. I was able to grab EVERYTHING between an `<h3>` tag and the next `<h3>` tag. But that pulls the `<script>` section which I don't want. Thanks again for continuing help! -Meghan

```
....
<div id="rt-main" class="sa3-mb9">
                <div class="rt-container">
                    <div class="rt-grid-9 rt-push-3">
                                                                        <div class="rt-block">
                            <div id="rt-mainbody">
                                <div class="component-content">
                                    <article class="item-pageDarkening">
<h3 style="text-align: center;">CHAPTER ONE - STEPHANUS GRAYLAND</h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;" dir="ltr"><span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">text.. ż/span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;" dir="ltr"><span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">text here</span><span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;"></span><span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">.</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>dljlg</p>
<span></span>
<p>dljlg</p>
<span></span>
   <p style="line-height: 1.15; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;" dir="ltr"><em><span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'arial black', 'avant garde'; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">&nbsp;</span></em></p> 

        <script type='text/javascript'>
Komento.ready(function($) {
    // declare master namespace variable for shared values
    Komento.component   = "com_content";
    Komento.cid         = "1211";
    Komento.contentLink = "...";
    Komento.sort        = "latest";
    Komento.loadedCount = parseInt(10);
    Komento.totalCount  = parseInt(56);

    if( Komento.options.konfig.enable_shorten_link == 0 ) {
        Komento.shortenLink = Komento.contentLink;
    }
});
</script>

<div id="section-kmt" class="theme-kuro">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    Komento.require()
    .library('dialog')
    .script(
        'komento.language',
        'komento.common',
        'komento.commentform'
    )
    .done(function($) {
        if($('.commentForm').exists()) {
            Komento.options.element.form = new Komento.Controller.CommentForm($('.commentForm'));
            Komento.options.element.form.kmt = Komento.options.element;
        }
    });

    </script>
    <div id="kmt-form" class="commentForm kmt-form clearfix">
                <a class="addCommentButton kmt-form-addbutton" href="javascript:void(0);"><b>Add comment</b></a>
                <div class="formArea kmt-form-area hidden">
            <h3 class="kmt-title">Leave your comments</h3>
```

Comment: Figured out how to strip just the story content out. So biggest hurdle overcome!     
`soup = BeautifulSoup(raw, 'lxml')    
article = soup.find('article')    
story = article.findAll('p',recursive=False)    
print(story)`